# How to install spree on a standalone alchemy-cms project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, alchemy-cms

When i tried to install spree on a standalone alchemy-cms project, getting these errors:

```
"Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree":
 In Gemfile:
   alchemy_spree (>= 0) ruby depends on
   spree (< 3.0, >= 2.3) ruby

   spree (0.30.1)"
```

Here's my Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'spree'
gem 'alchemy_spree', github: 'magiclabs/alchemy_spree', branch: 'master'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2','~> 0.3.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read   more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

```
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
```

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
    end

```
gem 'alchemy_cms', github: 'AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms', branch: '3.2-stable'
gem 'alchemy-devise', github: 'AlchemyCMS/alchemy-devise', branch: '3.2-stable' 
gem 'capistrano-alchemy', github: 'AlchemyCMS/capistrano-alchemy', branch: 'master', group: 'development'
```

Comment: It seems like you have `spree 0.30.1` installed. Please try `bundle update spree`